# How to download folder containing files as zip from server using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download a folder with its files in various mime type. My virtual path is "http://localhost/attachments/". My sub folders are "certificates/id". So when clicking on a grid i pass id to the download page. But it throws an exception like virtual path is invalid. 'http://localhost/attachments/certificates/id)'.

In below code, Request.Params[0] meant id, this points the endlevel folder which i want to make a zip folder.

Any guidance would be grateful.

```
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                string VirtualPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AttachmentsShowVirtualPath");
                string Path = string.Empty;
                Path = "certificates" + "/";

                string folderPath = VirtualPath + Path + Request.Params[0] + "/";

                zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.None;

                zip.AddSelectedFiles(".", Server.MapPath(folderPath), "", false);
                zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            }
```

Comment: Did you check that your folderPath String is correct? on which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: At this line it throws exception like, The virtual path is invalid.         zip.AddSelectedFiles(".", Server.MapPath(folderPath), "", false);               But the folder path where i point is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you using DotNetZip? I have never use it, but try changing the `.` to `*.*`

If not getting the file, try to do Directory.GetFiles to check if eveything is pointing correctly and your code has read permission over the directory https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Or try to use official Zip class from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx With this method: *ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I use Ionoc.zip package from nuget and included the following library file. "using Ionic.Zip";  I will let you know after applying your suggestions.